# Storing the RecordString with the FileHelper Class

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

We are using FileHelpers 2.0 in our project.  I have my record defined and have the data being imported correctly. After getting my array of generic objects:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<UserRecord>();
engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
UserRecord[] importedUsers = engine.ReadFile(_filepath);
```

After getting the records that errored due to formatting issues, I am iterating through the `importedUsers` array and doing validation to see if the information being imported is valid.

If the data is not valid, I want to be able to log the entire string from the original record from my file.

Is there a way to store the entire "RecordString" in the UserRecord class when the FileHelperEngine reads each of the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do that often at work handling the BeforeRead event and storing it in a field mOriginalString that is marked this way:

[FieldNotInFile]
public string mOriginalString;

You must use the last version of the library from here:

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/repository/download/bt65/20313:id/FileHelpers_2.9.9_ReleaseBuild.zip

Cheers